# PyTorch `torch.no_grad` vs `torch.inference_mode`

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent, inference

PyTorch has new functionality `torch.inference_mode` as of v1.9 which is "[analogous to](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.inference_mode.html) `torch.no_grad`... Code run under this mode gets better performance by disabling view tracking and version counter bumps."

If I am just evaluating my model at test time (i.e. not training), is there any situation where `torch.no_grad` is preferable to `torch.inference_mode`? I plan to replace every instance of the former with the latter, and I expect to use runtime errors as a guardrail (i.e. I trust that any issue would reveal itself as a runtime error, and if it doesn't surface as a runtime error then I assume it is indeed preferable to use `torch.inference_mode`).

More details on why inference mode was developed are mentioned in [the PyTorch Developer Podcast](https://podcasts.google.com/feed/aHR0cHM6Ly9mZWVkcy5zaW1wbGVjYXN0LmNvbS9PQjVGa0lsOA/episode/OWVmNjk3M2QtNjY2Ni00MmYyLTg4MTQtZWE3MDZiYjU2N2Rk?sa=X&ved=0CAUQkfYCahcKEwj4u96wo8XzAhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQAQ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `torch.inference_mode` is indeed preferable to `torch.no_grad` in all situations where inference mode does not throw a runtime error. Check [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-torch-no-grad-vs-torch-inference-mode/134099/2?u=timgianitsos).

Comment: FYI the first link has now rotted.

Comment: link is now removed

Comment: a more insightful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74197846/10805680

Comment: @simplyPTA Both my question and the link in my answer already mention view tracking, the version counter, and the PyTorch podcast episode - the answer you link does not mention anything additional that is responsible for the performance improvement